# Remove PHPMailer's From: 127.0.0.1 header

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, postfix-mta, email-headers

When I'm sending emails via well-known UA's (such as Outlook, Roundcube...) everything is fine

**but**

when I try to send programmatic email by using PHPMailer I got trouble in sent message headers:

```
Received: from www.domain.tld (hostname.domain.tld [127.0.0.1])
    by hostname.domain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTP id C4D7232C14EB
    for <me@somedomain.com>; Tue, 3 Feb 2015 16:23:17 +0100 (CET)
```

where `www.domain.tld` is url of website where is my script located, `hostname.domain.tld` is, obviously, server's FQDN.

Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->From = 'samplesender@sampledomain.tld';
$mail->FromName = 'Some sender name';
$mail->addAddress($emailadresa, $ime);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isHTML(true);                                 
$mail->Subject = 'Email subject';
$mail->Body = $htmlBody;
$mail->XMailer = ' ';
```

I've also noticed `from www.domain.tld` in headers which are not there when I send email via well-known UA's.

How to get rid of 127.0.0.1 headers when sending with PHPMailer?

Comment: That's Postfix adding that header. It says so right there in the `by` text. What's your concern with the origin IP anyway?

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHPMailer. That's your SMTP server saying that the mail was originally received from a "local" tcp connection.

Comment: But @MarcB, when I send with Roundcube that's also local tcp connection.

Comment: @mario I've been in deep trouble (blocked by Microsoft's servers) when I sent with `from: localhost 127.0.0.1` mistakenly

Comment: Roundcube may not be sending to localhost - it may be calling `sendmail` via the PHP `mail()` function (`isMail()` in PHPMailer).

Comment: Having localhost in a `Received:` header is something quite different than using a bogus sender in the `From:` header. You are imagining a problem where there is none, and ignoring the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using authentication:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = XX;
$mail->Port       = XX;
$mail->Username   = XX;
$mail->Password   = XX;
```

This way, you are going to use the host of the email account